# sql find sequence in table of point pairs

Tags: sql, ms-access, cross-join

I am struggling to find a solution to finde the sequence of all lines
in my table

there are entries like so

```
LineID     PKTID1     PKTID2
1          51         12
2          42         31
3          2          31
4          12         2
5          42         51
```

i will get a certain line number as as start, from there i have to find all ajoining lines like so

initial Line = 2 sequence would be

2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 1 -> 5 -> 2

I know how to do this in the front end (vb.net) using loops and such but is there a way to query this using sql - (in ACCESS)

```
SELECT 
    A.LineID, 
    A.PKTID1, 
    A.PKTID2, 
    B.LineID, 
    B.PKTID1, 
    B.PKTID2
FROM table AS A, table AS B
WHERE 
    (A.PKTID1 <> B.PKTID1 AND A.PKTID2 <> B.PKTID2)
    AND
    ((A.PKTID1 = B.PKTID1 Or A.PKTID1 = B.PKTID2) OR (A.PKTID2 = B.PKTID1 Or A.PKTID2 = B.PKTID2));
```

thats what i came up with so get all the joining Lines but i don't know how to order them the get the result i want.

Comment: There really isn't a way to do this in MS Access.  SQL supports such queries, particularly using recursive CTEs, but not MS Access.

Comment: unfortunately i am stuck with access, SQL server would be great but the application relies on ms access, but thanks anyway

Comment: Even if there was, it would probably be slower than your looping in VB.NET.